# Qt: Connect casted sender to a receiver

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

In my program, I have a QTableView which is set to display QStandardItemModel. 
I want to connect Model's

> itemChanged(QStandardItem*)

Signal to my SLOT. I did

```
connect(dynamic_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(ui->tableView->model()), SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(saveItem(QStandardItem*)));
```

But this always fails to connect (returns false). I am guessing it is because of dynamic_cast but I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @evilruff ui->tableView->model() returns QAbstractItemModel which doesnt have itemChanged SIGNAL

Comment: If you set the model to a `QStandardItemModel` before making the connection, then yes, it does have that signal. `QAbstractItemModel` is only the base type, but the actual object returned by `model()` is still a `QStandardItemModel` and you don't need to do a type cast. Maybe you just forgot to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class where `saveItem` is declared, or `saveItem` is not declared as a slot.

Comment: @alexisdm Thanks a lot. Autocomplete in qtcreator didn't work (when connecting) for obvious reasons, so I decided to cast. You should write an answer, so I can accept and I should improve my knowledge in polymorphism :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `QTableView::model()` returns a `QAbstractItemModel*`, if the model is set to a `QStandardItemModel*` **before** making the connection, the actual object will still be a `QStandardItemModel`, so the connection should work without the need to cast the pointer to that type.

Possible connection errors include: null pointer (by not setting the model before calling `model()`), bad spelling of the slot/signal name, not declaring a function as a slot/signal.

PS: It might be better to have the `QStandardItemModel` as a pointer member in your class, if you haven't already one, rather than using `model()` to retrieve it and having to repeat the cast each time you need to access the specific functions of the `QStandardItemModel` class. 

And as an additional benefit, the auto-completion would work since QtCreator would also know the actual object type.

Comment: I will accept this answer as this sums up everything. But autocomplete doesn't work (at least not for me).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting after setting model to table does the job. After setting the model to table, it returns QStandardItemModel, so there is no need to cast.

Comment: apparently you don't understand what dynamic_cast/qobject_cast do. It checks type of the object on runtime. It returns pointer to object if it is object of that type or null if object is not that type. static_cast is just information to compiler that you are sure what is the type of the object and compiler should perform conversion.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for the explanation. It is clear now why it didn't work. Compiler read connect(..) line and at that time model() was not the right object so dynamic_cast returned null. I should probably read more about something before using it.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `dynamic_cast` on `QObject`s, use `qobject_cast` as equivalent, it is much more safe (`dynamic_cast` has some problem with classes shared by libraries so this might be your problem, see [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#qobject_cast)).
In connect you don't need this cast anyway (this will help only in auto-completion), static cast should be Ok too.

In addition when connect fails, it prompts in logs what exactly went wrong, so check the logs.

Comment: It didn't show anything in log. That was surprising for me too, that's why I came here but my problem was more c++-sided. Anyways, thanks for reference, I will use qobject_cast from now on.